# Creating schemaExtension via graph explorer failing

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api

I tried the below query to add a `schemaExtension`, but it failed with an `Authorization_RequestDenied` response.

url: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions/`

post data:

```
{
  "id": "voctestextension",
  "description": "voc test extension",
  "targetTypes": ["User"],
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "trainings",
      "type": "Integer"
    },
    {
      "name": "incidents",
      "type": "String"
    }
  ]
}
```

Response

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "1d4d625d-99bc-46fc-9e7a-ac30d0840219",
      "date": "2018-03-14T13:17:45"
    }
  }
}
```

I have given the following permissions:

[image: permissions screnshot]

Answer (score 1):

In the JSON you're POSTing to Graph, can you try setting the owner property? It should be an application id of an app that you've registered.

From the [documentation page for creating schema extensions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/schemaextension_post_schemaextensions):

> The appId of the application that is the owner of the
>   schema extension. This property can be supplied on creation, to set
>   the owner.  If not supplied, then the calling application's appId will
>   be set as the owner. So, for example, if creating a new schema
>   extension definition using Graph Explorer, you must supply the owner
>   property. Once set, this property is read-only and cannot be changed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried doing this from my app, instead of graph explorer and it worked without setting the property(as it would have taken my app's appid). I guess the issue is that graph explorer app doesn't have this permission: Directory.AccessAsUser.All